# Recursive noexcept specification

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, noexcept

Testing with g++ 4.9 and clang 3.4, why does this code not compile:

```
namespace {

template<typename T>
constexpr auto f(T && t) noexcept {
    return true;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto f(T && t, Ts && ... ts) noexcept(noexcept(f(ts...))) {
    return f(ts...);
}

}   // namespace

int main() {
    f(true, 0, 5u);
}
```

But this code does:

```
namespace {

template<typename T>
constexpr auto f(T && t) noexcept {
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto f_helper(T && t) noexcept(noexcept(f(t))) {
    return f(t);
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto f_helper(T && t, Ts && ... ts) noexcept(noexcept(f(ts...))) {
    return f(ts...);
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto f(T && t, Ts && ... ts) noexcept(noexcept(f_helper(ts...))) {
    return f(ts...);
}

}   // namespace

int main() {
    f(true, 0, 5u);
}
```

The f_helper function does not have to be defined, it just has to have the correct return type specified by way of decltype in that case.

The first code also compiles for 1 or 2 arguments, but once I try to call it with 3 or more, I get errors about no matching functions to call. The clang error for the first code is:

```
source/main.cpp:9:59: error: call to function 'f' that is neither visible in the template definition nor
      found by argument-dependent lookup
        constexpr auto f(T && t, Ts && ... ts) noexcept(noexcept(f(ts...))) {
                                                                 ^
source/main.cpp:9:17: note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'f<bool, int, unsigned int>'
      requested here
        constexpr auto f(T && t, Ts && ... ts) noexcept(noexcept(f(ts...))) {
                       ^
source/main.cpp:16:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '<anonymous
      namespace>::f<bool, int, unsigned int>' requested here
                f(true, 0, 5u);
                ^
source/main.cpp:9:17: note: 'f' should be declared prior to the call site
        constexpr auto f(T && t, Ts && ... ts) noexcept(noexcept(f(ts...))) {
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The version with the helper [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/126cee2269269e96) if you pass 4 parameters to f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **3.3.2/1** The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any)...

*exception-specification* is syntactically part of the declarator. Thus, the function name is not in scope within its own exception-specification.

Comment: Although I'm technically not really calling this function recursively, I am calling a completely different function generated from the same template, which ultimately calls the single-argument function definition. Could that help me?

Comment: The name of that function template is not in scope at the point where you are trying to use it.

Comment: @DavidStone I think it can be found via ADL however?  Which opens things up to a hack, where you create a `template` function implementation with a dummy argument from the same `namespace`, and define the public-facing one in terms of said implementation.  Uncertain if this works.